# python method stealer

Tags: python, oop

How can I "steal" or copy a method from one class onto another class?

Example code:

```
class A(object):
  def foo(self):
    print "blah"


class B(object):
  foo = A.foo

B().foo()
```

Expected output:

```
"blah"
```

Instead:

> TypeError: unbound method foo() must be called with A instance as
>   first argument (got nothing instead)

Comment: This would make more sense if `foo` were a class method instead of an instance method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `__func__`:

```
>>> A.foo
<unbound method A.foo>
>>> A.foo.__func__
<function foo at 0x00BC5F70>
>>> class B(object):
...   foo = A.foo.__func__
...
>>> B().foo()
"blah"
```

Quoting [the docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/datamodel.html):

> An instance method object combines a class, a class instance and any callable object (normally a user-defined function).
>
> Special read-only attributes: __self__ is the class instance object, __func__ is the function object; __doc__ is the method’s documentation (same as __func__.__doc__); __name__ is the method name (same as __func__.__name__); __module__ is the name of the module the method was defined in, or None if unavailable.

Comment: Or, he could also just do `A().foo` instead of `A.foo.__func__`.

Comment: @jdotjdot `A().foo` is a "bound method", tied to that particular instance of `A`. That doesn't matter in the (probably simplified) example - since it does not use `self`, and could be replaced by a static/class method as well - but in more complex scenarios it would. I'm assuming the intent of the OP, though unstated, is to pick an useful method from an arbitrary class (i.e. not meant to be inherited from and not a mixin) and have the same method in his own class, but referring to/acting on instances of his class - and not of the original one.

Comment: you're right.  I was thinking in terms of this specific example, since `self` isn't required--but you are definitely right in that in the generalized, case, `A().foo` isn't a good call.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [class inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29) here.  Inheritance lets you create an object based on another object, inheriting all of its functions and attributes.

In this case, it looks like:

```
class A(object):
  def foo(self):
    print "blah"


class B(A):
  # You can add new methods or attributes here,
  #  or even overwrite those inherited from A if you
  #  really want to, though you have to be careful with that.
  pass
```

After that declaration,

```
>>> B().foo()
"blah"
```

This works because:

- You created class `A`, and created for it a method `foo`.
- You created class `B` *inheriting* from `A`, meaning that when `A` "gave birth to it," `B` was born with everything that `A` has.

  - In our case, `B` is an exact copy of `A`, since we didn't do anything else to it.  However, we could make changes or add more methods.

An example:

```
class A(object):
    def foo(self):
        print "blah"

class B(A):
   def newfoo(self):
       print "class A can't do this!"
```

Which in use, we'd see:

```
>>> A().foo()
blah
>>> B().foo()
blah
>>> A().newfoo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'newfoo'
>>> B().newfoo()
class A can't do this!
```

In particular, the reason that your code above didn't work is that when you tried to set `B.foo`, you wrote

```
class B(object):
    foo = A.foo
```

instead of

```
class B(object):
    foo = A().foo
```

When you wrote `A.foo` without the `()`, you were asking for the method straight from the `A` *type*, which wouldn't work in Python.  If you were to do `foo = A().foo`, what you'd be doing is instantiating an `A` object, and then getting a copy of its method `foo`, and then assigning it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that it is a bound method you are trying to steal, however, your example does not involve a function that uses instance state (`self`). Hence you have two immediate options:

1. Make the definition of `A.foo` a static method (`@staticmethod` decorator)
2. Decorate or wrap the function to pass an unused argument. E.g. using `functools`.

Eg.

```
import functools
stolen = functools.partial(A.foo, None)
```

This works because your method does not use instance state, and does not require creating a subclass.

To embellish a bit further, a bound instance method (like `A.foo`) expects a bound instance argument (`self`, where self is an instance of `A`). In normal usage, this first argument is passed automatically:

```
a = A()
```

Now:

```
a.foo()
A.foo(a)
```

...Are both equivalent. In the first case, the syntax `instance.bound_method()` infers `InstanceClass.bound_method(instance)` from a lexical viewpoint (`instance` resolves to `self`). This is why calling `A.foo()` will cause an error, since it expects an instance of `A`.

What the solution above does is to warp the function into one that passes a `None` as the instance, since the instance is never used anyway (there is no state-based logic). In the case of using staticmethod, it removes the 1st implied expected bound instance argument `self`.

Answer (score 0):

It works in Python 3 because *unbound methods* have been removed (cf. Guido van Rossum’s [article](https://python-history.blogspot.com/2009/02/first-class-everything.html)).

Note however that an unbound method was a function wrapper for checking implicitly that the first passed argument is an instance of the class defining the method, which is a precondition of the method that usually should not be violated. The error message gave you the correct solution which is inheritance:

```py
class B(A):
    pass
```

In general you should *not* steal a method from a non base class, because it will break `super()` calls (short for `super(__class__, self)`) in the non base class. Indeed, this program:

```py
class A(object):

    def foo(self):
        print "blah"
        super().__init__()


class B(object):
    foo = A.foo.__func__


B().foo()
```

raises:

```
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

This is because `super(__class__, self)` first checks that `self` is an instance (or subtype) of `__class__`, that is of `A`. Yet you passed a `B` instance and `B` is not a subclass of `A`. So the error message of Python 2 unbound methods was helpful.